# Passing a BroadcastReceiver object to a Fragment

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fragment

How can I pass a BroadcastReceiver object created and instantiated in an Activity, to a Fragment through Bundle maybe?

let me explain myself better:
I want to use BroadcastReceiver object inside the Fragment and then Unregister it in the parent's Activity onDestroy event. So I guess I can't instantiate it inside the Fragment. The only thing I came up is to instantiate it inside the activity and then passing it somehow into the fragment. Any suggestions how can this be achieved? Thanks

Comment: Why not instantiate the BroadcastReceiver in the Fragment?

Comment: Or, if @Egor's suggestion won't work for you, you could pass the just relevant data from the BroadcastReceiver to the Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Just call unregister from activity, fragments cannot register receivers.
Fragments can call getActivity().registerReceiver();

Build the broadcast receiver in the fragment and then register using getActivity().
Call unregister on activity destroy.

Comment: How can I destroy the Receiver instance from within activity if it was created inside the fragment at first place?

Comment: You don't need to destroy the instance, just unregister.